Chart function is diffeomorphism
I came across this exercise:

Let $(U,f)$ be a chart of a smooth manifold $M$. Prove that $f^{-1}$ is a local diffeomorphism.

It seems to me that $f^{-1}$ is a diffeomorphism, not just a local one. First of all, $f$ maps between the manifolds $U \subseteq M$ and $f(U) \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Choose the chart $(f(U),\text{Id}_{f(U)})$ of $f(U)$ and $(U,f)$ of $U$. Then
\begin{align}
f \circ f^{-1} \circ {\text{Id}_{f(U)}}^{-1} : f(U) & \to f(U) \\
x & \mapsto x \\\\
\text{Id}_{f(U)} \circ f \circ f^{-1} : f(U) & \to f(U) \\
x & \mapsto x
\end{align}
are $C^{\infty}$. So $f^{-1}$ is a diffeomorphism (and so is $f$). Then why add the term "local," and why ask about $f^{-1}$ and not just $f$?
